# Heroku environment variables specific to production

Tags: heroku, environment-variables

Does Heroku provide any environment variables that are specific to its production environment, so an app can easily distinguish between development/productions settings?

Right now I am just doing a test for HOME=/Users/myname for the development environment but that would not work if other developers want to work on my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku applications are *always* in production -- Heroku doesn't distinguish between development and production at all.

Heroku expects *you* to do development and testing on either your laptop, or another Heroku app completely separate from your production app.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just testing to see if the app was running with Gunicorn or on the Flask development server. Still...would be nice if Heroku gave some indication of the different environments.

```
if not "gunicorn" in os.environ.get("SERVER_SOFTWARE", ""):
    Config = DevelopmentConfig
else:
    Config = ProductionConfig
```